# Explaining Method of Pessimistic Estimators to Students

Tags: probability, education, np-complete

I need an alternative example for the Method of Pessimistic Estimators

I need to give a lecture about the method of pessimistic estimators to computer science students. My lecture must be based on the second part of [this lecture](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~nickhar/W12/Lecture16Notes.pdf) (only part 2).

The example based on LP and none of the students knows this material. 
I need to find a new (and more simple) example to explain the class the method of pessimistic estimator. 
The students learned probability and have good knowledge about the NP problems, but the example must be super simple and short in order for them to understand this method.

Thank you.